# SQLAlchemy Turning Floats Into Strings in SQL?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a model that roughly looks like this:

```
class Property(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Property'
    id = Column('Id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement='auto')
    name = Column('Name',  String(255))
    growth = Column('Growth', Float(2))
```

In MySQL, the Growth column is of type float(6,2).

When I query on Name, it will match just fine.

```
prop_obj = session.query(Property).filter(Property.name == fund_dict['name'])
```

If I add the float property, Growth, to the filter() clause it will not be able to match anything in the DB.

```
prop_obj = session.query(Property).filter(Property.name == func_dict['name'], Property.growth == func_dict['growth'])
```

Per the SQLAlchemy Docs, when I print out the SQL statement, I see this:

```
>>> statement = prop_obj.statement
>>> print(statement.compile(dialect=mysql.dialect()))

SELECT `Property`.`Id`, `Investment`.`Name`, `Property`.`Growth`
FROM `Property` 
WHERE `Property`.`Name` = %s AND `Property`.`Growth` = %s
```

Does the %s indicate that the substitution that's occurring is as a string and not a float?  That would explain why it's not matching.  If so, how do I make the substitution be a float instead of string?

I'm using Python 3.5 and SQLAlchemy 1.0.11.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `%s` is just a placeholder for parameters. [It is always `%s`.](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) It is **not** %-formatting the parameters into the string. You can see evidence of this in your query, where the literal being compared with `name` is not quoted.

What might be happening instead is you're trying to compare a slightly different floating point value with what is in the database. Because floating point numbers are not stored exactly, exact comparisons are problematic. What you should be doing instead is to see if the difference between your value and the one in the DB is less than some threshold:

```
func.abs(Property.growth - func_dict['growth']) < 0.01
```

Comment: Yep.  It was a problem with float.  I switched to Decimal and it works fine now.